# Combining missing term filter and range check in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I get zero result when combining range filter and missing filter together in a query. Query is given below. I get this issue only while combining missing and range individually both works good. 
Any help is appreciated on correcting the query or the code. I am elastic search 1.7.3 version.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": {
                  "missing": {
                    "field": "OrderData.XXXX.XXXXQueue"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "OrderData.XXXX.priority": {
                  "from": 1,
                  "to": 5,
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting an "or" condition? For example, results where either OrderData.XXX.XXXQueue is missing *or*  OrderData.XXX.priority between 1-5?

Comment: It is not or condition is a and condition.

Answer (score 1):

Does this Query get you the expected results?

```
 {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [{
                    "missing": {
                      "field": "OrderData.XXXX.XXXXQueue"
                    }
                  }, {
                    "range": {
                      "OrderData.XXXX.priority": {
                        "from": 1,
                        "to": 5,
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": true
                      }
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks scottjustin5000 even though the answer is not quit correct mainly because of the condition but that is easy to change. I have changed the answer and accepted it.

Comment: It is worth noticing that missing filter has been deprecated in elastic 2.x, in favor of exist filter..

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will consider removing it

Comment: I am wondering is there a way we can fix it apart from moving the range to inside bool condition. Ideally I am looking for various values for a bool condition with should and  another codition or range and so on.

Comment: @AnirudhModi  I don't find any information on missing being deprecated. I am referring to 2.x doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html

Comment: do you mean not moving the range condition into the nested bool? Either way, there are options. [combining bools](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/bool-query.html)  [filtered queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/bool-query.html)

Comment: @RaghuKNair seems like they have restored it...


But if you watch this github issue, they have clearly said to remove the missing filter in favor of exist.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14112

check this link also..

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-query.html

Comment: @scottjustin5000 I am aware of these options and my code is handling all these cases but unfortunately while combining missing win range I don't get any result moving to inner work only for this case but not scalable

Comment: hm, ok. i would have thought some variation on "filter": { "bool": {"should": {"missing": { }},"must" : {"range": { {} }}}} would give proper results.

Comment: I am deleting this question. It works fine with new environment. I need to debug and findout why it was not working in one of the environment.